# Meaning of "gay ladies' man"?

Tags: isaac-asimov, foundation

*Second Foundation* (Kindle edition, page 40):

> Bail Channis was one of these. He did not fear the mysterious Second Foundation. For that matter, he did not fear the Mule, and boasted of it. Some, perhaps, who disapproved of one at once so young and so well-off, waited darkly for the reckoning with the **gay ladies’ man** who employed his wit openly at the expense of the Mule’s physical appearance and sequestered life. None dared join him and few dared laugh, but when nothing happened to him, his reputation rose accordingly.

What does "gay ladies' man" mean?
What does he mean "at the expense of the Mule’s physical appearance and sequestered life"?

Comment: He uses the terms a few more times in the Foundation novels "*Thick Voice approached Toran. He was paunchy, his lower eyelids puffed darkly, and his hair was thinning out. There was a gay feather in his peaked hat, and the edging of his doublet was embroidered with silvery metal-foam.*" ***and*** "*Here she was on Kalgan. She had been to the great Central Theater—the largest in the Galaxy—and seen in person some of the singing stars who were famous even in the distant Foundation. She had shopped all on her own along the Flowered Path, fashion center of the gayest world in space.*"

Comment: Just to stress the point, *gay* applies to *ladies' man*, not *gay ladies'* applying to *man*.

Comment: Why do you think the fact that it happens to crop up in a Sci-Fi work makes this a Question about Sci-Fi or Fantasy? Would you truly not rather Ask the same Question somewhere to do with English?

Answer (score 47):

The [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/gay) defines the word "Gay" as

> *old-fashioned*
>
> **happy** (for example) "*We had a gay old time down at the dance hall*."

This was the common use of the word in the era when the book was written.  Obviously the word today tends to mean '*attracted to people of the same sex*', which makes this sentence seem unusual and dated.

Also: [Ladies' Man](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ladies%27%20man) was defined as:

> a man who shows a marked fondness for the company of women or is
> especially attentive to women

As to your second question, it means he made jokes at the expense of the Mule's odd physical appearance and solitary lifestyle.

Comment: Gay used to mean jolly. Warning, tv tropes link: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/HaveAGayOldTime/Literature

Comment: Not "dated". Notwithstanding the modern slang sense of "homosexual", in standard English the word gay still means gay, as in "a gay blade", "don we now our gay apparel", "the gaiety of nations", usw.

Comment: I remember people still using the word "gay" in its older sense in the 60s without feeling that they had to explain which meaning they intended. It was not an exact synonym of any other word, and in the 70s older people sometimes remarked on what a loss it was to the English language that it came to mean "homosexual." Someone who felt gay wasn't just happy, but felt transported, a bit drunk on happiness, even somewhat reckless.

Comment: @user14111: Did you notice that all your examples are phrases from well over a century ago?  Certainly most people still understand the older sense of *gay* when it’s used in older quotations and references, or in deliberate mock-archaism — but otherwise, it’s extremely rare in ordinary modern usage.  It’s certainly fair to call it *dated*.

Comment: @InvisibleTrihedron You could say "carefree" or "blithe" or "jolly" or "vivacious" or "jaunty"... As best I can tell, English is in a constant state of repurposing words and then repurposing other words to fill in the gap, so I expect sometime in the future it will have gone a full rotation where, through some intermediate number of repurposings, gay will be the new word meaning happy.

Comment: Would you explain more what “at expense of the mules phisical appearance  and sequestered life” mean?

Comment: I'd add that in this case Channis is contrasted with the Mule being named at least partly for a notable feature of hybrid animals (donkey x horse = mule = sterile) as implied in the last lines of Foundation and Empire.

Comment: @GuilhermeWoolley He makes jokes about (at the expense of) how the mule looks weird (physical appearance) and doesn't have any friends or go to parties (sequestered life).

Comment: Now I can't get the theme song to the Flintstones out of my head!

Comment: @PeterM - [Which version?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cBco_DApZVY)

Comment: @Valorum The one I grew up with, so the original.  Besides, I put that "movie" in the same realm as Highlander 2 etc  As far as I am concerned it doesn't exist.

Comment: Compared with my experience of the old usage, that definition of _gay_ misses a nuance suggesting _lighthearted, carefree fun_.

Comment: @PLL https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SOdHNGG9yWU

Answer (score 26):

The most relevant sense of *gay* here is may actually be that glossed by the *Oxford English Dictionary* as

> dedicated to social pleasures; dissolute, promiscuous; frivolous, hedonistic

although it accurately labels the sense as "Now *rare*."  However, it does still show up in publications as late as the 1960s (after "Now You See It...," which was first published in 1948).

This meaning of the word [which developed from the "happy" sense, and led in turn to the "(a) Of a person:  homosexual; (b) (of a place, milieu, way of life, etc.) of or relating to homosexual people" sense] suggests that Bail Channis is a partying, morally dissolute, and (in conjunction with *ladies' man*) sexually promiscuous individual.  He's just the kind of live-in-moment person who would frivolously mock the seemingly all-powerful Mule (or so it seems).

Comment: That definition of _gay_ and your conclusions (“morally dissolute”) seem to me too pejorative: in my experience the older usage usually simply suggested _lighthearted, carefree fun_, without implied criticism. Further, I think that “ladies’ man” is not very judgemental, and (as per the definition in Valorum’s answer) does not necessarily imply sexual activity.

Answer (score -6):

Well it either refers to a man who likes to charm gay ladies, or it's referring to him being happy, as you might imagine a successful ladies man would be.  I think the latter makes more sense.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you cite any definitions (as the other answers do) to support this reading?

Comment: Err, not a good answer. Because the question has context that strongly suggests the first of those is an incorrect reading